# Highcharts over extends parent on resize (using flexbox)

Tags: css, highcharts, data-visualization

*This question was initially a flexbox issue but has been altered to a highcharts resizing one*.

*The problem:*
I got the chart to resize perfectly in relation to it's parent (I was setting 100% height/width of it's parent) on window resize. The issue is that this only happens on a window resize event so when the page is initially loaded, the chart is not the size I want it (usually smaller)

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="datalogger">
    <div id="DataLoggerChartContainer" ng-show="dataAvailable"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS/LESS:** *(I was using flex but the styling does not matter)*

```
#datalogger {

  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;

  #DataLoggerChartContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**JS:** (*to resize chart*)

```
function reflowChart() {
    var parent = angular.element(element[0]);
    chart.setSize(parent.width(), parent.height());
}
```

@brightmatrix helped my realise that highcharts `setSize()` method will only resize the chart **ONCE** and is therefore not an ideal responsive solution. The `reflow()` and `redraw()`, as suggested, were not what I was looking for either. These methods aren't meant for responsiveness but mainly for if data is dynamically added to the chart and needs to be reloaded. `reflow()` is advertised on Highcharts API to dynamically resize to it's parent if it's size is altered. However, I think this only works if the window is not resized. So, the chart still has to be on the same sized window and the parent just has to resize within it's own container (on button click event for example *(as in Highcharts API)*)

*(Solution is below)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The solution:*

After digging through previous code in other areas of this application, I decided to attempt to redraw (manually - not using the `redraw()` method) the chart on a window resize event. For example:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    chart.destroy();

    initChart();
    reflowChart();
});
```

My `initChart()` function looks like this:

```
function initChart() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

My `reflowChart()` function is still the same as is mentioned above, however, the manual resizing does not matter as it resizes to the **CURRENT** height/width of the parent of the **CURRENT** window size. Because it is destroyed and recreated on each resize of the the window, this is an ideal solution.

**N.B:** It is not required but is recommended to call the `destroy()` method as it keeps the DOM nice and tidy.
Also, I call the `initChart()` and `reflowChart()` when the page first loads as well

I hope this helps anyone that may come across this problem in the future!

Comment: This is a really practical and elegant solution to this challenge. I appreciate you expanding upon your original question and providing a detailed walkthrough in your answer. I've my own sizing issue with hidden Highcharts visualizations and I've favorited this for my research.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation! I've had many Highcharts resizing issues myself and I believe this is one of the better solutions to the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as soon as you set fixed values for `chart.setSize()`, the responsive nature your chart is removed. I would suggest either adding percentage values, using the `chart.redraw()` function, or tying the `chart.reflow()` function to a `resize` event.

Here are the links to both functions in the API documentation so you can see which is best suited for your application:

- `chart.redraw()`: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw
- `chart.reflow()`: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately using either of these functions still gives the same effect. I tried removing my `reflowChart()` function altogether and disabling the `reflow` method but the chart still over extends it's parent. I've sorted a fix but don't know how valid it is: I added in `position: absolute` to the parent and set the chart's container to `relative`. Added back in the default `reflow` method and all seems to work. I don't know if it's valid to use those positionings with flex though as will it just override flex?

Comment: I can't speak from any knowledge of flex specifically, but the way you ordered the positions of your div elements has solved many CSS challenges for me in the past.

Comment: I've spoken with my supervisor and they gave me the go-ahead to do it like that :) thank you for you're input!